# How to let mac computers search for files on my ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, samba, search, macosx

I have a ubuntu server 22.04 setup and it is sharing files using samba.

the mac computer can connect to it and use the files just fine. My problem comes in when i try and search for a file or folder that it will just not work on mac. Other windows or linux machines on the network searches just fine. i have use elasticsearch with fs Crawler in the past but it doesn't work well it will search one day and not the next or even search now and 5 min later the search doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This is a mac problem not of Ubuntu (server) as proven by "Other windows or linux machines on the network searches just fine" You need to ask mac users ;) on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks i will post the same question on those forums and see if they can help